# CSS: prevent background from scrolling

Tags: css, gwt

I have created a modal popup box. I want the background body to be fixed while scrolling. I googled and found to add `background-attachment: fixed;` but with no success.

Does background-attachment: fixed; only works for images? as stated in (w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)

> /* Set background image to fixed (don't scroll along with the page)*/

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: Could you please post the full code, or even better yet create a working fiddle?

Comment: Please, post your HTML, CSS, jsfiddle and etc.

Comment: The above should work, so something else must be off - if you post the full code we should have a better idea.

Comment: code is GWT not vanilla HTML

Comment: I will try to crop from browser inspector

Comment: It must still be outputting something? Also it's worth mentioning that in your question and adding to the tags.

Comment: sorry, can't make the code public. Does background-attachment: fixed; only works for images?  as stated in (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp) "/* Set background image to fixed (don't scroll along with the page) */
    background-attachment: fixed;"

Comment: try adding overflow: hidden to your container

Comment: If you can't share your code then your question is off-topic as that's a requirement for debugging questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [sorry, can't make the code public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33167966/css-prevent-background-from-scrolling/33168266#comment54144148_33167966)

So I will just make a guess that could work.

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the body of the page the moment the popup opens.

Comment: Yes, this works! but ended up finding  **Window.enableScrolling(false)** (thanks to eclipse :-)  which ends up producing :     `getViewportElement().getStyle().setProperty("overflow",
        enable ? "auto" : "hidden")`